# Vagrant unable to mount SMB after upgrade to 1.7.4

Tags: vagrant, smb

I'm using vagrant on windows 8, with the hyper-v provider starting a windows server 2012 box.

Before I updated to vagrant 1.7.4 I was on version 1.7.2, and everything worked.

But after updating I am getting an error when it is trying to mount the shared folder:

```
The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

cmdkey /add:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /user:DOMAIN\user /pass:Password

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

Exception calling "RegisterTaskDefinition" with "7" argument(s): "The user
name or password is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052E)"
At C:\tmp\vagrant-elevated-shell.ps1:58 char:1
+ $folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task_name, $task, 6, $username, $password,
1, $n ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

I have replaced the details from the line:

```
cmdkey /add:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /user:DOMAIN\user /pass:Password
```

With placeholders for obvious reasons. I did try and run the command above in the VM and I get the following output:

```
CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
```

So I assume it is working correctly. Has something changed or broken in 1.7.4?

Comment: Seeing this too when upgrading to 1.7.4. Going back to 1.7.2 resolves it but I would really like to use some of the new config for the hyperv provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a fix for this.

Our password contained dollar signs ($), these were being stripped out in the vagrant-elevated-shell.ps1 script.

I have forked the vagrant repo and made the change and made a pull request - https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/6452

To patch your local environment, you can find the communicator.rb file on your local machine at:

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.7.4\plugins\communicators\winrm\communicator.rb

(provided you used the default setting in the installer)

Comment: With the last version (2.0.1), it is the same problem if the passord contain a simple quote ('). I would never have found a solution without this post, thanks a lot for saving a lot of my time.

Comment: Glad I could help @Xav987